# How to create tooltips as bubble boxes in Qt?

Tags: qt

I have trying implementing tooltips as bubble boxes in qt, without any luck. Even tried placing a css file in qt having code to mainpulate tooltips, but of no use.
Any methods to create tooltips as bubble boxes in qt widgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QBalloonTip` which is an internal class defined in :

- Qt 5:

  `QtDir/Src/qtbase/src/widgets/util/qsystemtrayicon_p.h`
- Qt 4:

  `QtDir/src/gui/utils/util/qsystemtrayicon_p.h`

`QBalloonTip` inherits `QWidget` and it is implemented in `qsystemtrayicon.cpp` at the same directory. It has the following method to show a balloon tip:

```
void QBalloonTip::balloon(const QPoint& pos, int msecs, bool showArrow)
```

You can modify the source code of this class to have your desired balloon tip.