# How to create bubble tooltips in PyQt?

Tags: pyqt, tooltip

I'd like to have a tooltip that looks like below. I don't know how pyqt's tooltips looks like on windows but I'm on linux and it's a plain rectangle.

[image: ][1]]

Comment: The image is what you desire, right? You probably have to do it yourself, defining a custom shape, intercepting tooltip events, position smartly. Qt has a ballon tooltip in QSystemTrayIcon but they only use it internally. See also [How to create tooltips as bubble boxes in Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658937/how-to-create-tooltips-as-bubble-boxes-in-qt).